# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file specified (with SetWallpaperAsync)

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using the following method to set the background image of my uwp app:

```
    async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync(string localAppDataFileName)
    {
        bool success = false;
        if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Local/" + localAppDataFileName);
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
            UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
            success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file);
        }
        return success;
    }
```

When I call await SetWallpaperAsync("StoreLogo.png"); I get the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file specified". I'm guessing the problem is that I have the file stored in the wrong place but I have no idea where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call await SetWallpaperAsync("StoreLogo.png"); I get the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException,but I have no idea where to put it.

The problem is that you get file with wrong path. You can access files in the **local app data** store using the `ms-appdata:///local/` uri scheme. For example:

```
ms-appdata:///local/myBinaryFile
```

And you could also use [ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) API the get file

Use the `ms-appx`  URI scheme to refer to a file that comes from your **app's package**. and you could also use [`InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation) API.

For more detail, you could refer [URI schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes)